# Smallest 3-ellipses that contain triangles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry, conic-sections

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse

**Question:** How does one find and characterize the smallest 3-ellipses (n-ellipses with n =3) that contain a given triangle? 'Smallest' can mean 'least area' or 'least perimeter' or... and *may* have different answers. Are 3-ellipses for which the 3 vertices of the triangle are themselves the foci good candidates?

And what about the largest 3-ellipses *inscribed* in a given triangle?

**Note:** Versions of these questions for n>3 and 3-d can also be considered. Maybe one can prove (say): smallest n+1-ellipse containing any triangle is smaller than the smallest n-ellipse containing the triangle.

**Variants** (September 10th, 2021): Instead of  3-ellipses - and multifocal ellipses - one can ask the above questions with convex *Cartesian Ovals* (with 2 or more foci). Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_oval

**Note added on October 18th, 2023:** We can also ask inside-out versions of these questions; for example, given a 3-ellipse, is the triangle for which it is the smallest containing/ largest embedded 3-ellipsoid unique? How to find it/them?

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124371/237) may help,
especially the citation to

> Nie, Jiawang, Pablo A. Parrilo, and Bernd Sturmfels. "Semidefinite representation of the $k$-ellipse." In *Algorithms in Algebraic Geometry*, pp. 117-132. Springer, New York, NY, 2008.

[image]

The polynomial for a $3$-ellipse has degree-$8$.
"We express this polynomial equation as the determinant of a symmetric matrix of linear polynomials."

Comment: The Wikipedia image showing the nested $3$-ellipses for increasing distances suggests it would not be difficult to binary search for the (approximate) distance such that the $3$-ellipse includes two foci and passes through the third. This would be the smallest $3$-ellipse.

Comment: Thank you. Another possibility is probably to consider only 3-ellipses which pass thru *all* vertices of the triangle - but then, it seems at most only one of the vertices can be a focus and finding the position of the other foci would become another problem!