# The optimal embedded and enclosing cardioids for a triangle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid

Earlier posts with similar questions: [Smallest 3-ellipses that contain triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403370/smallest-3-ellipses-that-contain-triangles) and [Curves of constant width that contain triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403485/curves-of-constant-width-that-contain-triangles)

Questions: Given any triangle,

- how does one find and characterize the smallest cardioid that contains it?
- how does one find and characterize the largest cardioid contained in it?

Note:  Optimal containing cardioids with "smallest" defined in terms of area and perimeter should be the same - and likewise for the embedded cardioids. The answers to above could give a couple of special centers and special directions for each triangle - for a cardioid is a curve with an orientation given by say, the line from its center to its cusp.

**Note added on October 18th, 2023:** We can also ask inside-out versions of these questions; for example, given a cardioid, is the triangle for which it is the smallest containing/ largest embedded cardioid unique? How to find it/them?